# Performing API calls from a mobile client, reauthorizing the session if necessary

Tags: java, session, state-machine

I'm working on mobile app which doing requests to a server's API. I want to develop module that doing following:

- get authorization key already exists in previous session
- connect to server api and read server StatusLine answer code
- if answer code is 403 then try to re authorize
- when authorization is passed process server answer body

I implement this with state-machine:

```
enum ConnectionState {
    checkAnswer, reAuth, processLinks, endProcess
}
```

And made process in while-loop:

```
        int authCount = 0;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        ConnectionState state = ConnectionState.checkAnswer;
        boolean processConnect = true;
        while (processConnect) {
            switch (state) {
                case checkAnswer:
                    httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
                    final int serverAnswer = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (403 == serverAnswer) {
                        state = ConnectionState.reAuth;
                    } else {
                        state = ConnectionState.processLinks;
                    }
                    break;
                case reAuth:
                    if (++authCount > MAX_AUTH_ATTEMPTS) {
                        state = ConnectionState.endProcess;
                        break;
                    }
                    auth.invalidateAuth();
                    if (!auth.doAuth()) {
                        Utils.log("could not authorize api");
                    } else {
                        state = ConnectionState.checkAnswer;
                    }
                    break;
                case processLinks:
                    if (null == httpResponse)
                        throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponse is null");
                    processLinks(httpResponse, imgLinks);
                    state = ConnectionState.endProcess;
                    break;
                case endProcess:
                    processConnect = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Finded impossible state: " + state.toString());
            }
        }
```

What do you think about such code organization for this task? How to write it more elegantly?

Comment: It is common to name enum elements in capital case such as CHECK_ANSWER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Ibalazscs that [StatePattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) makes sense - using a switch to drive changes in behavior is a code smell.

Given that this state machine has only one end state, you could ditch the processConnect boolean, and just check for end state...

```
ConnectionState state = ConnectionState.checkAnswer;
while(! ConnectionState.endProcess.equals(state) {
  ...
}
```

You also might want to consider whether ConnectionState should implement an interface to make it extensible.  See Item #34 "Emulate extensible enums with interfaces", Effective Java Second Edition, by Joshua Bloch

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). The actual state-dependent code could be handled in the enum.